# WorksheetCollection set range

Tags: c#, excel

I have this line of code for setting date style:

`doc.Worksheet[i].Cells.Columns[z].ApplyStyle(dateStyle, dateStyleFlag)`.

What I would really like is to set the style starting from some row index r to end of column.

Somewhere I saw `ws.get_Range("a1").EntireRow.EntireColumn.Select()` but I'm not able to do `ws.get_Range`.

I do have `ws.Cells.Ranges[x]` but not sure of usage in my case.

So the characteristics of my need are: 1. Select a a range 2. range should be till end of column/populated column 3. Use indices, not cell names (**not** e.g. A1)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure if this is what you are after or not, but this is an example of how you would take column 3 (C) and make all of its value a date format.

```
Sheet.Range[Sheet.Cells[Sheet.UsedRange.Row, 3],
    Sheet.Cells[Sheet.UsedRange.Row + Sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, 3]].
    NumberFormat = "MM/dd/yy";
```

Also, I don't think there is any real issue in just formatting the entire column.

```
Sheet.Columns[Column].NumberFormat = "MM/dd/yy";
```

If this isn't what you had in mind, maybe clarify what you are expecting.